# jquery + loop through html table rows where checkbox is not checked

Tags: jquery, checked

I have the following loop that looks for `checked checkboxes` and edits each row accordingly.

```
$("table.authors-list").find('input[type="checkbox"][name^="treated"]:checked').each(function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        priceInput = row.find('input[name^="transportprice"]');

    priceInput.val(treatedtransportcostperton.toFixed(2));
});
```

what is the opposite of `:checked` as I want to loop through the table where the checkbox are not checked?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [:not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) :

```
  $("table.authors-list")
     .find('input[type="checkbox"][name^="treated"]:not(:checked)')
     .each(function () {...});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with Using Selectors

$("table.authors-list").find('input[type="checkbox"]name^="treated"]:not(:checked)').each(function () {

}